# Adding debug and release versions of libraries to a VS solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have my solution laid out as follows

```
src/Project1
src/Project2
src/Project...
bin/*.{dll,exe}
lib/Debug/*.dll
lib/Release/*.dll
```

All of the projects are set to build to the top level bin dir.  I include a number of 3rd party library dependencies in the lib folder, I like having them here as they then get versioned along with the software in the source repo.

Normally I have each project add a reference to the Debug versions of the libraries but when it comes to releasing I have to manually change all the references to point to the Release versions.

My question is, is there a way to have Visual Studio automatically pick the DLL based on the build configuration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about C#? In that case you can manually adjust the project file to reference the correct library like this:

```
<Reference Include="Debug\XXX" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'"/>
<Reference Include="Release\XXX" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Platform'"/>
```

or if the directory names match the config names exaclty you can even do:

```
<Reference Include="$(Configuration)\XXX"/>
```

and if needed you can also pull in the platform names the same way

Answer (score 2):

Modify the MSBuild settings in your project file and add conditions to the references.
Like so:

```
<Reference Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <HintPath>D:\debug\libdll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <HintPath>D:\release\lib.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

- To edit the project file first unload it and then press edit proj file.

Some reference info:

- [MSDN msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx)
- [Tigris msbuild tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> Go to Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VC++ Directories

Use the `$(Configuration)` variable to specify the correct folder

e.g. If you want to use *C:\mystuff\lib\Release* when in release mode, but *C:\mystuff\lib\Debug* when in debug mode, add the following line to *Library files*:

`C:\mystuff\lib\$(Configuration)`

Here `$(Configuration)` is either *Debug* or *Release*

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @stijn's #2 solution above, but showing this with the HintPath way:

```
<Reference Include="CoolWidget">
  <HintPath>..\..\coolWidgetPath\bin\$(Configuration)\CoolWidget.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```